# How to nest context within a context (already in another context) to make a shared example within a shared example for an RSpec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm learning Ruby/Rails and am starting with understanding my work's code base and adding to a test. I'm having some trouble understanding how to set up a shared example. In a describe block that has different contexts I want to work within one context, putting two nested contexts within it that will change a variable in their outer context.

In the code below the `context 'and the attachment is a zipfile' do` is the context of the describe block I want to work in. I want to change the variable `contentType` by having two different contexts for `'application/x-zip-compressed'` and `'application/octet-stream'`.

Can I set up the two inner-inner contexts to change the contentType variable with `let(:contentType)` or will that not work because it's a symbol which I understand as a constant that can't change?

Originally, this just has the `type` of `"file1"` hash set to `"applicatoin/x-zip-compressed"`. I'm exploring a way to use a shared example make the type a variable that I can have change depending on context.

```
  context 'and the attachment is zipfile' do
    let(:encoded) { true }
    let(:data) { File.read( Rails.root + 'spec/fixtures/test_files/test.zip') }
    let(:expected_status) { 'new' }
    let(:attachments){{
      "file1" => {
        name: "test.zip",
        type: contentType,
        content: payload,
        base64: encoded
      }
    }}
    context 'and the attachment type is zip' do 
      let(:contentType) { 'application/x-zip-compressed' }
    end

    context 'and the attachment type is octet-stream' do 
      let(:contentType) { 'application/octet-stream' }
    end


    it 'saves each zipped file as a separate payload' do
      expect(TransactionPayload.all.size).to eq 2
```

Comment: yes, you can setup variables defined with let inside various context to get various behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can setup variables defined with let inside various context to get various behaviour. But you that definitions should be enclosed descendant context blocks to the place, where the variable is used. But to use it `it` clauses **must** be declared inside the variable definer context:

```
describe 'the attachment is zipfile' do
  let(:encoded) { true }
  let(:data) { File.read( Rails.root + 'spec/fixtures/test_files/test.zip') }
  let(:expected_status) { 'new' }
  let(:attachments){{
    "file1" => {
      name: "test.zip",
      type: contentType,
      content: payload,
      base64: encoded
    }
  }}
  context 'and the attachment type is zip' do 
    let(:contentType) { 'application/x-zip-compressed' }

    it { $ request with compressed }
  end

  context 'and the attachment type is octet-stream' do 
    let(:contentType) { 'application/octet-stream' }

    it { # request with octet }
  end
end
```